# C# Prepared SQL Statement does not replace @Value

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, prepared-statement

I got this code:

```
command = new SQLiteCommand(dbConnection);
sql = "SELECT IFNULL(MAX(RowId), 1) AS Id FROM @name";
SQLiteParameter nameParam = new SQLiteParameter("@name", System.Data.DbType.String, 100);
command.CommandText = sql;
command.Parameters.Add(nameParam);
command.Prepare();

foreach (String name in liste)
{
    command.Parameters[0].Value = name;
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
    ret = ret + number;
}

dbConnection.Close();
return ret;
```

What am I doing wrong? When executing this statement I always get the following exception:

> "near "@name": syntax error".

So this means the SQLstatement does not get updated by the prepared statement parameter, why is that?

Comment: you can't pass a table name as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass a table name as a parameter.

You could add it to the string when forming the SQL statement, but then you are running the risk of SQL injection, so do not do this.

Another thing you could do is have the user select the table from a dropdown and create the SQL doing this, since you already know all the possible tables.